# How should we handle drill recomendation questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've seen three questions ([1](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-are-some-good-strength-exercises-for-marathon-runners) [2](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/48/which-workouts-will-most-help-my-basketball-ability) [3](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/50/recommended-drills-to-help-keep-your-eye-on-the-ball)) that specifically ask for drills, workouts, exercises, etc to help with a specific condition.

If they already comprise 12%<sup>(1)</sup> of the site, we should be prepared to expect a number of questions like this.

My issue with them is that they are soliciting an incomplete list; that is to say it would not be reasonable to expect a list of all exercises capable of training a particular attribute of the athlete.

Should we be accepting these questions? What can advice can we give askers of such questions in order to help them make the necessary edits to conform to our format?

<sub>Note 1: I recognize the small sample size and the poor statistical reliability implied by this statement.</sub>

Comment: Great question! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I think these questions are *a)* unavoidable, *b)* can provide huge value to the community.

I totally agree that these are "incomplete list" type questions. However, I think that as long as the question is specific enough, an expert will be able to provide a comprehensive answer that will *a)* give the asker and the community a good grounding in the field and *b)* point them into the right direction for further research.

After all the voting on the answers will show which one is either the most widely recognised as effective technique/drill or which answer cover the most ground.

Lastly, if a question gets very many answers that seem appropriate then nothing stops it from being a community wiki which is again a great resource for the community. most voted questions on SO are almost all community wikis with long list of things and they are of great value.

Comment: I suspect if Joel and Jeff could go back in time they would not have even created community wiki. I personally do not consider it a viable option to anything. To quote [Grace Note](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) "questions rarely, if ever, need community wiki".

Comment: I still don't see how community wiki answers don't provide value... Maybe I'm not fully following your argument.

Comment: There are many things that could provide value but do not fit our QA format. If a question, by design, will solicit community wiki answers, it is a poorly phrased question *for the StackExchange format*. This is not to say that it wouldn't add value, because it very well might. But we should not do things just because they add value. The most voted questions on SO are all community wikis, but if they were asked *now* instead of then, most of them would be closed as not constructive to the format.

Comment: SO I guess this is a tradition/"the way we do things" question rather then usefulness question. It's important to make this distinction and then evaluate what is important: tradition or value to the community. TBH at the moment I cannot make the call. May pay off to look at the SE mission statement :)